# Differential Forms and Area

Tags: differential-forms

I think I'm just misunderstanding something here, but in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ there exists a $1$-form (in fact infinitely many) $\omega$ such that for any region $S,$ we have $\int_{\partial S} \omega = \textrm{area}(S).$ Can we say the same on the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$? From what I can see, the answer is no, as the area form on the unit sphere is given by $x dy \land dz + y dz\land dx + zdx\land dy,$ which is not exact (or even closed). However, thinking about the punctured sphere (i.e. the sphere minus the north pole), it seems that such a form should exist since it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Is this line of reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Stokes' theorem we have $\int_{\partial S} \omega = \int_S d \omega$, so the problem is whether a given volume form is exact, or equivalently whether it's zero in top de Rham cohomology. On a compact oriented Riemannian manifold, a volume form is never exact (in fact it generates top de Rham cohomology), but in the noncompact case this need not be true.

$S^2$ is compact but $S^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, like $\mathbb{R}^2$, is noncompact and in fact contractible, so its second de Rham cohomology is trivial.

(What you've written by itself is not enough because the diffeomorphism between the punctured sphere and $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have in mind doesn't respect the volume forms you have in mind.)

Comment: So given a volume form on the punctured sphere, it must be exact? Is this because such a form is closed - why is this last statement true though? Lastly, as another example, if we were to consider the 2-torus, which has second de Rham cohomology $\mathbb{R}$ and is an orientable compact manifold, we can draw the same conclusion as for the sphere? Thanks!

Comment: Top forms are always closed; you can just compute directly that they have zero exterior derivative. You can draw the same conclusion for the torus.

Comment: From what I understand though we are taking $\omega$ on the boundary of a 3-manifold , but then $d\omega$ is not necessarily 0 on the 3-manifold? Perhaps the point is that the diffeomorphism takes closed/exact forms to closed/exact forms under pullback from the punctured sphere to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @lyj: what 3-manifold?

Comment: Wait sorry I'm adding one to my dimensions; okay just to clarify then: the volume 2-form on the unit sphere is in fact closed so I was incorrect in the original question; the point is that it's not exact, which follows from what?

Comment: oh i see - integrating the form over the unit sphere yields a non-zero value so it can't be exact